# Django - can't loop through custom templatetag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I've created custom `categories_tag` templatetag as follows:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

from ..models import Category

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def categories_tag(context):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return categories
```

And now want to loop through this tag like:

```
<h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
{% for i in categories_tag %}
   <a href="">i</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But in browser doesn't seem anything. What can be wrong with my code ?

Comment: The context here is categories cause you assigned the objects to it soo loop though categories

Comment: @ngawang13, doesn't work, man

Comment: I have edited your work. Check through it

Comment: @ngawang13, didn't change anything...

Comment: Single dot when importing model and try that with the code that i edited

Answer (score 0):

```
{% categories_tag as ct %}
  {% for c in ct %}
    {{ c.name }}
  {% endfor %}
```